# How to get specific array items from specific range list

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I've 10000 of array record and someone says to retrive the index record for data of range form 5000 to 5500 indexed data.

How can I do this in php or javascript?

Comment: with both and also with sql (if you have a database in back) ...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use array_slice function where passing array as first parameter, offset as second parameter and number of elements as third parameter as follow

```
$subArray = array_slice($input, 5000, 500);
```

please visit [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) for more information on array_slice

Comment: If I need to do this with JS array then?

Comment: that would be  var subArray = input.slice(5000, 500);